# Double quotes in html non-literals? Which is the correct one: type="checkbox" or type=checkbox?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, tags, html

so I have this...

`< input type="checkbox" id="chvre" value="1"/>`

Here, it makes sense that the `id` value is in quotes, as it would be a string identifier. But what about the `type` value? Isn't `checkbox` a type, like String and Boolean? Why do I keep seeing these supposedly non-literals between double quotes? Is it bad practice? What should I aim at getting used to doing?

Furthermore, what if I want the value of value (that "1") to be a number instead of being treated as a string? If I read that value in javascript, `var val = document.getElementById("chvre").value` I have to use the `parseInt()` thingy.

So, what's the right way of doing these things? Do I just double quote everything? Should I not?

Answer (score 2):

When using attributes, you must remember the rules of XML, as well as the rules of general attribute use.

These are as follows:

- Attributes must occur within the opening tag of an element. The close tag is merely a place marker and should have nothing else between the brackets except the slash and tag name.
- All attribute names must be in lower case.
- All attributes must have a value.
- All attribute values must be in double quotes. Remember that a double quote and two single quotes are not the same thing.
- All attributes must be included in a space separated list, with no other characters between them.

**More Info:**

- http://www.daaq.net/old/xhtml/index.php?page=xhtml+attributes

Comment: Useful.
But aptana's autocomplete adds the checkbox value without the quotes. I figured that since it did it, it wasn't necessary. Hence the doubt. Is aptana not following proper standards with this?

Comment: It's not required by HTML (as opposed to XHTML), but it is better practice.

Comment: @navand: Aptana is an editor, it may or may not follow the standards; it could be the settings problem as well. You should stick to standard and put quotes around attribute values.

Comment: @SLaks: That is true. Probably OP has html doctype for which apatana doesn't use double quotes although as you said it is always a good practice to place them.

Comment: This stuff only applies to XHTML. I would say that for an attribute with optional value (such `selected` or `disabled`), it's better to omit the value.

Answer (score 1):

HTML and XML have no conception of string vs. non-string literals. (They're markup languages, not normal languages)
Double-quotes are optional in HTML, but there is no semantic difference `type=checkbox` and `type="checkbox"`.

All attribute values should be in double-quotes.

Comment: If everything should be within double quotes, why does aptana's auto-complete add type=checkbox instead of type="checkbox"?

Comment: There's absolutely no requirement to surround an attribute value in quotes, so long as the value does not contains spaces.